# while2.c in C Primer Plus

Tags: c, while-loop

The original code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int n = 0;

    while (n++ < 3);
        printf("n is %d\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

I wonder why the result is "n is 4" not "n is 3"?

Comment: The indentation is wrong, the printf line should not be indented - look carefully at the line above.

Comment: Step through your code [in a debugger](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what happens here is that you compare to a good value, lets say 2 < 3, then the postincrement happens and you end up with 3 inside the loop

An example:

```
// you probably want to remove the ; at the end of the while like this:
while (n++ < 3) { // the posticrement will update the value n
    printf("n is %d\n", n); // here n will have an updated value
}
```

It is also a good practive to use {} instead of indentation.

Comment: Thanks for the help. In this example, the authors added the ";" at the end of the while and the indent at the beginning of line 7 in purpose. I guess when n is 3, the while loop will be terminated but the n++ statement will still add 1 to n. Therefore, the value of n finally becomes 4.

Comment: @buaaqq, No problem. I am glad that I could help. Yes, exactly. If this answer helped you could you please mark it as the answer to the question?